# Incorrect screen size of Cordova project on iPhone XR / XS / iPad Pro 11

Tags: ios, cordova, size, screen

I was able to export my test project from Rpg Maker MV tool using Cordovafor iOS.

The resolution of the project is 1920x1080. When I export no problems, it works perfectly and the screen measurements are almost correct on all iPhones and iPads except:

- iPhone XR / XS / XS Max
- the new iPad Pro 11 and 12.9"

How can I resolve via Xcode and insert the correct visualization?

I always see a white bar on the left side, as in the picture.

I read between the various posts of solutions to white bars, such as inserting the string in the index.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no", initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
```

After that I deleted the splash screen assets, and inserted it into the config.xml this string:

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-1242h@3x~iphone" />
```

Nothing to do, it is as if it did not find the files, and the visualization becomes smaller even though centered.

How can I solve it? I am using xCode 10.2.1.

Comment: I don't see any picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my meta & splash config that I believe works on all iOS devices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">

<splash height="1125" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-2436x1125-screen.png" width="2436" />
<splash height="640" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-1136x640-screen.png" width="1136" />
<splash height="750" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-1334x750-screen.png" width="1334" />
<splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-2208x1242-screen.png" width="2208" />
<splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-2048x1536-screen.png" width="2048" />
<splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-1024x768-screen.png" width="1024" />
<splash height="640" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-960x640-screen.png" width="960" />
<splash height="320" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/land-480x320-screen.png" width="480" />
<splash height="2436" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-1125x2436-screen.png" width="1125" />
<splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-640x1136-screen.png" width="640" />
<splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-750x1334-screen.png" width="750" />
<splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-1242x2208-screen.png" width="1242" />
<splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-1536x2048-screen.png" width="1536" />
<splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-768x1024-screen.png" width="768" />
<splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-640x960-screen.png" width="640" />
<splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/port-320x480-screen.png" width="320" />
```